# Getting error in IOS ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow

Tags: react-native

getting this error in new react-native 0.63.3 and my xcode version is 11.3.1
i know one solution is to upgrade the xcode but its not working in RN 0.62.2

[image]

Comment: did you find the solution? i am facing the same problem

Comment: @Rajesh update your xcode